# How to get time of FlipClock?

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I use **flipClock.js** in my site.I want get  time of clock In seconds.

How to do this?

```
$('.clock').FlipClock(600, {
            clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
            countdown: true,
            language: 'fa-ir',
            callbacks: {
                stop: function () {
                $('#timeout-dialog').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet what you want to get is [time delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing), not just *time*, but *time until/after smth*, and in your case, time until the moment FlipClock has been instantiated + 600 seconds. In Javascript, it's usually expressed in milliseconds, by just a number. What you could do to calculate this time delta is to share the target time between two callback functions, placing the variable into outer scope:

```
let timeStarted = null;
const targetTimeDelta = 5000;
const clock = $('#clock').FlipClock(targetTimeDelta / 1000, {
  clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
  countdown: true,
  callbacks: {
    start: () => {
      timeStarted = new Date();
    },
    stop: () => {
      const timeStopped = new Date();
      console.log(Number(targetTimeDelta) - Number(timeStopped) + Number(timeStarted));
    }
  }
});
```

Here, `timeStarted` is first declared outside of the scope of a function passed to `start` callback. It makes it accessible from another scope, the scope of a function passed to `stop` callback. It also makes it accessible from anywhere else, and generally, [globals are bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad), but it's only for demo purposes here. Perhaps you know already how to encapsulate this value properly so it doesn't get redefined occasionally elsewhere in the code.

Also, see [codepen](http://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/pNydgX?editors=1010#0) for that.